# GCC error could not create c++ files during pyqt4 install in osx lion using xcode 4.5.1

Tags: macos, mac, python, xcode, qt

Intel mac osx lion 10.7.

Installed xcode 4.5.1 version and also installed command line tools from xcode preferences.

Could not install python 3.2.x from its source code since i wanted to create so files from python-c functions.

Hence i end up using python3.2.x.dmg and successfully installed it and Qt.dmg

Finally i wanted to install PyQt module using python for i386 architecture, but found the following issue.

```
    python3 configure.py --use-arch i386
Determining the layout of your Qt installation...
This is the GPL version of PyQt 4.9.1 (licensed under the GNU General Public
License) for Python 3.2.2 on darwin.

Type '2' to view the GPL v2 license.
Type '3' to view the GPL v3 license.
Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.

Do you accept the terms of the license? yes
Found the license file pyqt-gpl.sip.
Checking to see if the QtGui module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtHelp module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtMultimedia module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtNetwork module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDBus module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDeclarative module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtOpenGL module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtScript module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtScriptTools module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtSql module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtSvg module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtTest module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtWebKit module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtXml module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtXmlPatterns module should be built...
Checking to see if the phonon module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtAssistant module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDesigner module should be built...
Qt v4.7.4 free edition is being used.
Qt is built as a framework.
SIP 4.13.2 is being used.
The Qt header files are in /usr/include.
The shared Qt libraries are in /Library/Frameworks.
The Qt binaries are in /Developer/Tools/Qt.
The Qt mkspecs directory is in /usr/local/Qt4.7.
These PyQt modules will be built: QtCore, QtGui, QtHelp, QtMultimedia,
QtNetwork, QtDBus, QtDeclarative, QtOpenGL, QtScript, QtScriptTools, QtSql,
QtSvg, QtTest, QtWebKit, QtXml, QtXmlPatterns, phonon, QtDesigner.
The PyQt Python package will be installed in
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages.
PyQt is being built with generated docstrings.
PyQt is being built with 'protected' redefined as 'public'.
The Designer plugin will be installed in
/Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/designer.
The PyQt .sip files will be installed in
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/share/sip/PyQt4.
pyuic4, pyrcc4 and pylupdate4 will be installed in
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin.
Generating the C++ source for the QtCore module...
sip: Usage: sip [-h] [-V] [-a file] [-b file] [-c dir] [-d file] [-e] [-g] [-I dir] [-j #] [-k] [-m file] [-o] [-p module] [-P] [-r] [-s suffix] [-t tag] [-T] [-w] [-x feature] [-X id:file] [-z file] [file]
Error: Unable to create the C++ code.
```

Hope I m not the first one to face such installation error as i had already installed this earlier successfully using xcode 4.1. Hope there is some changes in GCC(livm GCC in xcode 4.5) which may be the cause.

If any one hav a key to fix this would be appreciated very well.

Thanks.

Comment: Just from looking at this error, it would seem to me that the problem is not GCC (GCC does not create source code), but SIP, which displays its usage message (it must have been used incorrectly).

Comment: space in the configuration path was the problem and installed very well. thanks BenjiWiebe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue and installed successfully sip and pyqt4

Space should not be in the path from where we build / configure.

once i removed the space from configuration path and installed sip and pyqt4 successfully

Thanks BenjiWiebe and everyone

Comment: you should be able to accept this answer as the correct answer in a matter of hours/one day... not quite sure.